# AWS S3 and CEPH / Rados Bucket permission inheritance

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, ceph, radosgw

I'm having issues with creating a publicly readable bucket. I'm working in a CEPH / Rados store using the Amazon aws-sdk v 1.60.2

I created a bucket similar to many different tutorials with

```
s3.buckets.create('bucketName', :acl => :public_read)
```

I then uploaded a number of files up to `s3.buckets['bucketName']` But when I go in and look at specific permissions for the bucket and it's internal objects the bucket I see has READ permissions granted to AllUsers group as well as FULL_CONTROL set to the user I created the bucket with. The objects however do not inherit the anonymous read permissions. I need the objects in the bucket to be readable anonymously.

As a note I see these permissions when I run `s3.buckets['bucketName'].acl`. When I try to run `s3.buckets['bucketName'].policy` I get the following error that makes no sense:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: unexpected token at '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Name>erik.test</Name><Prefix></Prefix><Marker></Marker><MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys><IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated></ListBucketResult>' (JSON::ParserError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.60.2/lib/aws/core/policy.rb:146:in `from_json'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.60.2/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb:621:in `policy'
    from test.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

The above error looks like aws-sdk is calling a json parser on an XML string which shouldn't be happening.

I cannot simply upload the objects with explicit permissions because my project would have BOSH uploading to the store automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately policies are inherited, so while it is possible to read the list of objects in a bucket, as it stands the anonymous read permission doesn't continue for the items uploaded.

http://ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/

Comment: out of date, link is dead.